# Parsing template language in php

Tags: php, parsing, templates, internationalization

Some days ago I came across [jquery.i18n](https://github.com/wikimedia/jquery.i18n) from the wikimedia foundation that enables to translate strings like `Welcome, $1` and `Found $1 {{PLURAL:$1|result|results}}`.

I'd like to recreate that functionality in PHP just for educational purposes.

I was able to create a parser that parses strings like `Welcome, $1` but now I'm looking to recreate the second functionality `Found $1 {{METHOD:$1|parameters|...}}` but I cannot figure out how to create some functionality to do that.

Can anyone push me into the right direction? I've already looked at the sourcecode of the jquery.i18n library and I am not looking to implement another existing translation library, just create one on my own.

This is what I've got for the simple argument parsing function:

```
public function parse($message, $replacements)
{
    if (strrpos($message, '{{') === false) {
        return $this->simpleParse($message, $replacements);
    }
}

protected function simpleParse($message, $replacements)
{
    return preg_replace_callback('/\$(\d+)/', function ($match) use ($replacements) {
        $key = $match[1] - 1;
        if (isset($replacements[$key])) {
            return $replacements[$key];
        }

        return $match[0];
    }, $message);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work well:

```
function parse($msg, $args) {
    return preg_replace_callback('~{{(\w+):(.+?)}}|\$(\d+)~', function($m) use($args) {
        if(strlen($m[1]))
            return parse_func(
                strtolower($m[1]),
                explode('|', $m[2]),
                $args);
        return $args[$m[3] - 1];
    }, $msg);
}

function parse_func($name, $params, $args) {
    foreach($params as &$p) {
        if(preg_match('~^\$(\d+)$~', $p, $m))
            $p = $args[$m[1] - 1];
    }
    return call_user_func_array("handle_$name", $params);
}

function handle_plural($value, $sing, $plu) {
    return intval($value) > 1 ? $plu : $sing;
}

// works!

$msg = "Found $1 {{PLURAL:$1|mouse|mice}} and $2 {{PLURAL:$2|apple|apples}}\n";

print parse($msg, [1, 5]);
print parse($msg, [6, 1]);
```

The idea is to replace everything (dollars and braces) at once and take an appropriate action in the replacement function. You can add more 'methods' like "plural" by defining additional `handle_xxx` functions.